# How can we retrieve public key from private key ( protected with passphrase ) using python's Cryptography library?

Tags: python, ssh, cryptography, public-key-encryption, python-cryptography

I want to use python's [Cryptography library](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/) to get public key from private key(which could be protected by passphrase also). How can I do that similar to Python's [CryptoDome library](http://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/examples.html) ?

Comment: By using the `public_key()` method.

Comment: James K, can you point me to the link? I couldn't find it.

Comment: [Here it is](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/rsa/#key-interfaces) for RSA.  And [here it is](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/ec/#cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric.ec.EllipticCurvePrivateKey) for elliptic curves, and [here](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/dh/#key-interfaces) for diffie-hellman. Each type of private key has a method called `public_key()`.

Comment: @JamesKPolk Using this API, I am not getting whatever _ssh-keygen -y -f <key_file>_ returns as public key. Apparently there can be infinite public keys for a given private key and also the public key it is generating starts with **BEGIN PUBLIC KEY**. The above ssh-keygen command returns public key like: _ssh-rsa ABCD_ . Can I get public key whatever the above ssh-keygen command returns? The way I am retrieving public key using the Cryptography library is: https://pastebin.com/UHjKbC0Q

Comment: I googled and looks like I have to use _serialization.Encoding.OpenSSH_ and _serialization.PublicFormat.OpenSSH_ . Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```py
key_file = open('key.text', 'rb')
private_key = serialization.load_pem_private_key(
    key_file.read(),
    password=None,
    backend=default_backend()
    )
public_key = private_key.public_key()
```